# I need to know if a chunk of text is encrypted or not or if there is a message in it (More info in desciption)

Tags: python, encryption, python-requests

I am making an automated request for a website and the website is sending out a request with a `formData` which has a chunk of data which I don't know where it came from.

At first, I thought this text was encoded with `base64`, but it did not give me anything that was readable. I am hoping if someone out there has some knowledge or some software which they can use to decrypt the portion of the `formData`. I am not 100% sure that it is encrypted, as I am not very experienced, but I am confident it is because otherwise it would just be a chunk of text and nothing more.

I'm including a paste-bin below, it should have two sections "bg:" and "z:". They are separate chunks of text. Thank you in advance for interacting with this question!
    [Paste-bin link](https://pastebin.com/reF1eRaJ)

```
import requests
requests.get(url, data=formData)
```

Comment: It's obviously base64 encoded using the modified base64 alphabet for URL encoding. Determining what it means is up to you.

Comment: Damn, why didn’t I think of that earlier. I’ll see, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are searching in the wrong place. There’s no magical software that can decode unknown encoding or encryption. At most we can measure things like entropy (high entropy points to encryption or compression) or alphabet size (64 points to base64, etc).

However, if this encoded data is present in your browser’s request, then it was produced inside the browser. Try inspecting the page and the JavaScript to find how this data was produced. The code may be intentionally obfuscated in order to make your task harder, but it’s still easier to reverse engineer the request creation than to just guess the algorithm.

Comment: Thank you! You seem like you know what you are talking about so I will go your route. I tried it already. There are about 8000 lines of code, and it is heavily obfuscated. I have made out some functions and lines of code which I fully understand although it is difficult. Thanks again!

Comment: My advice is to go slowly and methodically. Draw diagrams and re-implement pieces of functionality yourself. Heavily use debugger to check the values of variables. Google any constants you find, if this is a standard algorithm it will easily identify it. Good luck!